# Button always displays on top in FrameLayout

Tags: android, android-framelayout

I have FrameLayout like this:

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="changeColor"
        android:text="new button"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="some text"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

The problem is that the button is displayed on top while FrameLayout class overview tells us this: "Child views are drawn in a stack, with the most recently added child on top".

Comment: you can use Linear-layout

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Incorrect overlay behavior in FrameLayout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33017735/incorrect-overlay-behavior-in-framelayout)

Answer (score 101, accepted):

**Update:**

in android 21+ after introduction of [elevation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#setElevation%28float%29) one can play with elevation attribute of various widgets to put them on top of one another. [here](https://material.io/design/environment/elevation.html) is a material design guide for `elevation` values.

**for api < 21 :**

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33018254/1529129)

> Buttons in Lollipop and higher have a default elevation to them which
> causes them to always draw on top. You can change this by overriding
> the default StateListAnimator.
>
> Try putting this into your button XML:
>
> `android:stateListAnimator="@null"`
>
> The FrameLayout should now cover the
> button.

Comment: this answer saved me. but i would prefer to add the system button elevation android uses to the other views in the framelayout. how can i get the button elevation dp valu android is setting ?

Comment: Yes, this removes animation which uses elevation. Your button now become a simple ImageView. The proper solution is to adjust other items elevation to be higher than your button which is accepted answer.

Answer (score 22):

In the Android 5.0 (API 21) and above, you must add **android:elevation** into the view.

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="changeColor"
        android:text="new button"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="some text"
        android:elevation="3dp"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

Put your `Button` inside `FrameLayout`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="new button" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="some text" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

As the official android documantation points out:

> FrameLayout is designed to block out an area on the screen **to display
>   a single item.** Generally, FrameLayout should be used to hold a single
>   child view, because it can be difficult to organize child views in a
>   way that's scalable to different screen sizes without the children
>   overlapping each other. You can, however, add multiple children to a
>   FrameLayout and control their position within the FrameLayout by
>   assigning gravity to each child, using the android:layout_gravity
>   attribute.

It's better if you put your `Button` and `Textview` in a `RelativeLayout` inside the `FrameLayout` like:

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="some text"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="changeColor"
            android:text="new button"/>
        <RelativeLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Apperently **android:stateListAnimator="@null"** works only for API = 21 or higher,
So for those who target API<21 use this, it worked for me :D

```html
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="changeColor"
            android:text="new button"/>
    </FrameLayout>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="some text"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

[FrameLayout](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html) should be used to hold a `single child view`, because it can be difficult to organize child views in a way that's scalable to different screen sizes without the children ***overlapping each other***.

You should use **LinearLayout** or **RelativeLayout** in **FrameLayout** .
Like this way

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="changeColor"
        android:text="new button"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="some text"/>
   </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Why it's difficult? You just could put in the order they get in xml? And that's how documentation explains it. I just can get how it works. Why it makes difference with buttons and imageviews. It shouldn't even know about that.

Answer (score 1):

For API < 21 you cant use android:stateListAnimator="@null" or change the elevation. In my case I used 2 frame layouts embedded in a constraint layout.
As the frame layouts can be stacked upon each other there is no need to change the elevation of the textview.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/my_daybutton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/cal_button_background"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:gravity="start|top"
        android:paddingTop="2dp"
        android:paddingStart="2dp"
        android:paddingEnd="2dp"
        />
</FrameLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="bla"
        android:textSize="9sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        />
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put elevation FrameLayout or any parent there you are going to load you fragment like

```
android:elevation="@dimen/dimen_20"

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen_0"
    android:id="@+id/ready_to_scan"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:elevation="@dimen/dimen_20"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>
```