# Floating action button always displays on top

Tags: android, floating-action-button

I am trying to show textview on the top of Floating Action Button. Inside FrameLayout, I have 1 FAB and 1 TextView:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|start"
    android:padding="@dimen/fab_margin">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fabAddSeller"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        app:backgroundTint="#3780f4"
        android:stateListAnimator="@null"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvSellRecordCount"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/sell_record_counter"
        android:layout_gravity="top|end"
        android:text="12"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="10sp" />

</FrameLayout>
```

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33018342/2752399), I have added

> android:stateListAnimator="@null"

to FAB - no difference. I have put TextView after FAB - no effect.

[image]

How to show another view on top of FloatingActionButton?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24459352/how-can-i-add-the-new-floating-action-button-between-two-widgets-layouts

Comment: elevation is an option? I'm not sure which is your minSdk

Comment: Use a RelativeLayout !! try to set TextView Property **android:layout_above="@id/fabAddSeller"**

Comment: @GuilhermeP, yeah I set elevation to my TextView, and now it is on top. By the way minSdk = 14

Comment: @GuilhermeP, can you post this as answer and I will accept it - other people who will face this issue will know how to solve it

Comment: @JoeRichard I'll... However, I'm affraid this solution may not work for pre- Lollipop devices.. I think elevation works only for API > 21... Also, which elavation did you use? For me, it works only with elevation=6dp

Comment: @GuilhermeP, android:elevation="10dp"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In Android Studio, I could fix after adding an elevation to the text view:

```
android:elevation="6dp"
```

It seems that FAB has 5dp of elevation.

However, I'm not sure if this totally works to you since elevation is available for API>=21.

Try to make some tests in real devices...

Maybe, `android:stateListAnimator="@null"` is enough in real devices/emulator.

**UPDATE**

After adding `app:elevation`, this fix started to work with older APIs as well

```
app:elevation="6dp"
android:elevation="6dp"
```

Comment: in this case, if i long press fab, it rises under my round view

Comment: need to set elevation 12dp+ for this case

Answer (score 1):

Replace FrameLayout with **RelativeLayout** and add

```
 <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        ...
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvSellRecordCount"
        ...
        />
```