# Draw View from XML file under other TextView

Tags: android, xml, canvas, view

I'm trying to draw a Canvas in a View and show this View under some TextViews I defined in my XML file.
Everytime I test the App it just doesn't start on the device.

However, the parts themself work:
When I change the `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` in the `onCreate()` to `setContetView(new CustomView(this));` it works, but of course without the textView.

**My *activity_main.xml*:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sampleText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Some Text"/>

    <com.example.simon.drawtest.CustomView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/sampleText"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**My *MainActivity.java*:**

```
package com.example.simon.drawtest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 }
}
```

**My *CustomView.java*:**

```
package com.example.simon.drawtest;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.view.View;

public class CustomView extends View {

    private Paint paint;

    public CustomView(Context context) {
        super(context);   
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.GRAY);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawColor(Color.BLUE);
        canvas.drawCircle(200, 200, 100, paint);
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be putting your custom view first? Meaning higher in the file, before the TextView?

Comment: @milosmns doesn't really make a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

show your whole `activity_main.xml`...

both `View`s should be wrapped in e.g. `FrameLayout`

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sampleText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Some Text"/>
    <com.example.simon.drawtest.CustomView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/sampleText"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

edit: ok, so you have `RelativeLayout`.. also note that with Android 5.0 [elevation attribute](https://developer.android.com/training/material/shadows-clipping.html) was introduced and you may have some problems with drawing order like [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32307245/button-always-displays-on-top-in-framelayout)

also... your `TextView` is first in XML so it will be drawn before your custom view (drawing by order if elevation isn't set)

also... `android:layout_below="@+id/sampleText"` below means under in vertical axis. try to remove this line

edit: user post exception stack trace in comments, so below I'm pasting proper answer for his case (comment copied):

> your error stack says
>
> Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:
>  [class android.content.Context, interface
> android.util.AttributeSet]
>
> you have only one constructor with Context
> only, system needs also one with additional AttributeSet. check out
> [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9195713/do-i-need-all-three-constructors-for-an-android-custom-view) question & answer, apply proper constructors for your CustomView

Comment: added the rest of it. I had them wrapped in RelativeLayout. Is there a difference (significant to the problem)?

Comment: Calling `super.onDraw()` will only draw the background and any registered drawables, right? It may be "just" the ordering of the child elements in the layout :)

Comment: calling super in `onDraw` in this simple example will surely draw transparent background only (so.. nothing), but when project will grow this super call might do some additional work, especially when user is drawing custom shapes or use some Material-introduced params/atts :)

Comment: Ok i removed the `below`attribute and moved CustomView before TextView. The problem remains. Do I acctualy call an Instance of CustomView?

Comment: try to set fixed dimens for both your `View`s - e.g. 100dp for `layout_width` and `layout_height`. note that `wrap_content` isn't recognizing custom shapes drawn inside `onDraw` and this `View` will be 0px x 0px size (you should also overrride `onMeasure` method and set dimens in there). it works when you use `setContetView(new CustomView(this));` becaue then your `View` fullfil whole `Activity`

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try this as soon as I'm back from work. Theoretically speaking: The app should still run, shouldn't it? Why is this problem causing it to not run at all?

Comment: you have to clarify what is going on when you start your app on device.. is it even launching? - really weird if not, because of one-line change... launching and crashing? - show some logcat with exception stack trace. or launching and showing blank "page"? - all my suggestions considers this scenario ;) but in this case its weird that you don't see `TextView` (custom drawing like you do is really tricky and there is a lot of dependeces)

Comment: The Application is simply crashing. The error logcat is displaying is: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class com.example.simon.drawtest.CustomView

[Gist-Link to complete error-code](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/baecffc681fa555ac9f5718422a7941b)

Comment: I should add that I changed some lines. So the error is at the line where i say `<com.example.simon.drawtest.CustomView`

Comment: your error stack says `Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.content.Context, interface android.util.AttributeSet]`. you have only one constructor with `Context` only, system needs also one with additional `AttributeSet`. check out [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9195713/do-i-need-all-three-constructors-for-an-android-custom-view) question & answer, apply proper constructors for your `CustomView`

Comment: YES!! this was the problem. Thank you so much for your help. Everything else was correct but this.
Can you maybe edit your answer and add this to it, so other people will see it and i can mark it as the correct answer.
Thanks again!

Comment: done :) always paste your exception stack trace, as you see it helps a lot with tracking your problem. good luck!