# Elements in FrameLayout are invisible

Tags: android, android-layout, invisible, android-framelayout

I am a newbie in Android development.
Trying to put Button and ImageView inside FrameLayout, but they are invisible (they do exist on the layout, but not drawn).

My layout:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/OuterFrame"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:foreground="@drawable/flb1_off">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/show_dialog"
        android:id="@+id/showDialogBtn"
        android:onClick="showDialog"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="#123456"
        android:textColor="@color/abc_background_cache_hint_selector_material_dark"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/flb"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:contentDescription="@string/content_desc" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The api version is 19.
The interesting thing is that button clickHandler works ok, but button itself is invisible.

I put all children to single child view, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32307364/7092030), but without success.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I think `android:foreground="@drawable/flb1_off"` is the problem.

Comment: @SHAHMDMONIRULISLAM, you are right! Substitution android:foreground to android:background fixed it!

Comment: I have added a answer. Can you please accept it? @Nicolas

Comment: Done! Thx @SHAHMDMONIRULISLAM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is coming from this line:

```
android:foreground="@drawable/flb1_off"
```

You need to change it.

Answer (score 0):

Substitution android:foreground to android:background fixed it, as [SHAH MD MONIRUL ISLAM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2548051/shah-md-monirul-islam) offered.