# Android RelativeLayout zIndex not working (anymore)

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I don't understand this issue. I'm pretty sure I used to do this, yet in this case, the zindex ordering is not followed, and the TextView below is hidden behind the button:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<Button
    android:text="Button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp" />
<TextView
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

I have restarted Android Studio, but even worse, this is the same on my device too, so its not an Android Studio bug. What is the issue here exactly?

Comment: please have to look this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27132825/z-index-in-relative-layout/38534042)

Comment: TextView should be above Button based on z indexing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use the elevation

```
android:elevation="10dp"
```

here is you can see your [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27132825/z-index-in-relative-layout/38534042)

Answer (score 0):

If you add any views to Relative Layout, It places your view above another view if you don't use layout alignment like layout_above/layout_below/layout_leftof or rightof etc